# Запись в БД множества параметров

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Возникла задача записать множество различных параметров (опций) которые генерируются при помощи `select`, `text-field` и множества `check-button`, `radio-button`.

Как лучше всего их хранить в БД SQLite?

Может стоит отвести в таблице один столбец назвать его `param` и записывать в него данные в JSON виде? Или как лучше хранить такие данные?

Comment: а что вы потом с этими данными делать будете?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте колонку и храните Json. Главное что бы поиск по нему не было

Если будете поиск делать, тогда структурно разделите их по группам.

Comment: Остался только вопрос как в rails сохранить половину параметров в json?

Answer (score 1):

С SQLite вариантов у вас почти нет. Только сериализация или хранение отдельной таблицей.

Первое реализуется [одной строчкой](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html):

```
serialize :fields, JSON
```

...и этим, фактически, вы потеряете возможность делать запросы с условиями на эти поля.

Если вам нужен поиск по этим полям, вам придётся сделать их отдельной моделью и таблицей и делать к ним запросы такого вида:

```
Thing.joins(:fields).merge(
  Field.where(key: 'foo', value: 1..5))
```

В зависимости от необходимости хранить там значения разных типов, условия выборки могут усложниться на преобразования типов в SQL.

Но замечу, что вы **не хотите** пользоваться SQLite в веб-приложении, которым будет одновременно пользоваться больше одного человека.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать Postgres, то в нем есть расширение [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) и под него написан [gem](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore). Это расширение позволяет хрaнить в поле множество пар `ключ-значение` (и то, и другое - строка), и производить выборку по содержимому таких полей.

**P.S.**

Поторопился, не дочитал. Вы ведь написали, что у вас SQLite.
Это как раз один из минусов использования Hstore.

Ещё один минус - необходимость на новой машине каждый раз ставить это расширение, даже для запуска в режиме *development*. Но от этого можно уйти, используя докер или подобное решение.

Comment: *необходимость на новой машине каждый раз ставить это расширение* -- миграции же это автоматизируют, нет?

Comment: @D-side да, если установлены нужные библиотеки, которые нужно устанавливать - http://askubuntu.com/questions/354686/postgres-doesnt-have-hstore-extension.

Comment: Да и для гема `pg` их нужно ставить. Это адресовано больше вопрошающему, мол, минус довольно ватный. А ещё, с 9.4 есть JSONB! В отличие от hstore, умеет произвольную вложенность, но меньше поддерживаемых типов.